Summable subsets of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$
Background. Given the set $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ with the sum defined by $(f + g)(i) := f(i) + g(i)$, we say that a family $F = \{f_t\}_{t \in I}$ of elements of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is summable if, $\forall i \in \mathbb N$, the set $\{t \in I : f_t(i) \ne 0\}$ is finite. In this case we define the sum of the family $F$, $\Sigma F \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, as:
$$(\Sigma F)(i) := \sum_{\substack{t \in I \\\\ f_t(i) \ne 0}}f_t(i)$$
(note that it's always a finite sum). Given $S \subseteq \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ we'll indicate with $\Sigma S \subseteq \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ the set of all sums of summable families of elements of $S$.
Questions.

Exhibit a set $C \subseteq \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ such that $|C| = \aleph_0$ and $|\Sigma C| > \aleph_0$.
Prove that if $F = \{f_t\}_{t \in I}$ is summable, then the set of $t \in I$ such that $f_t \not \equiv 0$ (i.e. is not identically zero), is at most countable.
Let $S$ be the set of the functions $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is finite and include $0$ ($\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is the support of a function, i.e. the subset of $\mathbb N$ where the function is non-zero). Prove that $\Sigma S \ne \Sigma \Sigma S$.
Given $S \subseteq \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ prove that if $\forall f,g \in S \ f + g \in S$, then $\Sigma S = \Sigma \Sigma S$.

My attempt.

We can take the set $C = \{f_n \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} | \forall i \in \mathbb N\setminus\{n\} \ f_n(i) = 0 \land f_n(n) = n\}$. Obviously $|C| = \aleph_0$, and, since every set in $\mathcal{P}(C)$ is summable (and we always have different sums) we get $|\Sigma C| = 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$.
By contradiction, if $\kappa := |\{t \in I : f_t \not\equiv 0\}| > \aleph_0$, then there are $\kappa$ distinct non identically zero functions in $F$, each of these differs from one of the others for at least one value, so I think from this we get to the contradiction that there should be more than $\aleph_0$ naturals but I cannot write it down formally.

I'm really struggling with all the notation in this problem, which is making it hard to visualize what happens/having ideas for 3 and 4, any hint/suggestion?

Good work so far. I think for notation/visualisation it's good to bear in mind that the elements of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ are really sequences. So for example you can think of question 2 as: "if you have a $\aleph_0\times\kappa$-dimensional grid (think of each sequence as a row) of real numbers such that every row has a nonzero number and every column has only finitely many nonzero numbers, then $\kappa$ cannot be uncountable". To finish your argument, try arguing about the cardinality of the set of nonzero numbers in this grid. For 3: start by trying to work out what $\Sigma S$ even looks like...

... Think of some sequences not in $S$ and see if you can write them as a sum of elements of $S$. Hopefully you will realise that there is something of an obstacle there. Lastly I think 4 is quite hard. The basic idea is that you can use 2 to assume that an arbitrary element of $\Sigma\Sigma S$ is of the form $\sum_{i\in\Bbb N}\sum_{j\in\Bbb N}f_{i,j}$. Then you should come up with a clever partition of $\Bbb N^2$ into finite sets $X_1,X_2,\dotsc$ such that $g_n=\sum_{(a,b)\in X_n}f_{a, b}$ is a summable family. This is quite "analysis-flavoured". Let me know if you'd like a bigger hint.

@IzaakvanDongen thank you very much for your help as always! For 2: since each row has a non-zero real element, and since I'm assuming to have $\kappa$ distinct rows I've to "split" these elements in order to have finitely many of them aligned in each column, but this cannot be done. Formally speaking, let $N$ be the set of non-zero real elements in the grid (eventually counted with repetition), we know $\aleph_0 < \kappa \leq |N|$, and, at the same time 1/2

let, $\forall i \in \omega$, $ c_i$ be the cardinality of non-zero elements in the $i$-th column (counted eventually with repetition), we've that $|N| = \sum_{i \in \omega} c_i \leq \sum_{i \in \omega} \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, which is a contradiction. Is this correct/formal enough/what you had in mind? 2/2

Yep, pretty much! If you want to be a bit more formal in your answer, you would talk about $|{(t, i) : f_t(i) \ne 0}|$, which you can write as a union in two different ways.

@IzaakvanDongen ah right, this way should work: $\aleph_0 < \kappa \leq \left | \bigcup_{t \in I} { i \in \omega : f_t(i) \ne 0}\right|  = |{(t, i) : f_t(i) \ne 0}| = \left | \bigcup_{i \in \omega} { t \in I : f_t(i) \ne 0}\right| \leq \aleph_0$, shouldn't? About 3: since $\forall f \in S , 0 \in \operatorname{supp}(f)$ a summable subset of $S$ must be finite, otherwise for $i = 0$ we'd have an infinite sum, moreover $ \operatorname{supp}(f)$ finite implies that the function is eventually constant so $\Sigma S$ contains only finite sums of eventually constant functions. 1/3

So every function in $\Sigma S$ has itself finite support, but not necessarily $0$ belongs to that support (e.g. the identically zero function belongs to $\Sigma S$ along with finite support (non identically zero) functions such that $f(0) = 0$). Now a summable subset of $\Sigma S$ can be infinite and so for example I can have a non eventually zero real sequence that doesn't belong to $\Sigma S$ but it does belong to $\Sigma \Sigma S$. 2/3

If everything I said is correct I just need to explicitly exhibit a non eventually zero real sequence that belongs to $\Sigma \Sigma S$ and it doesn't belong to $\Sigma S$ to conclude 3, and that should be easy, am I right? 3/3

I think you have a typo in your cardinality calculations - either the unions should be disjoint unions $\bigsqcup$, or the sets in the unions should be sets of pairs $(t, i)$. But the rest sounds right to me! This was 95% of the work required to solve 3 - you are right that what's left should be easy.

@IzaakvanDongen you're right I was thinking to the pairs $(t,i)$ for the sets in the unions but I wrote it down incorrectly! About 3 I can just take the sequence $a_i = 1$,  $\forall i \in \omega$, for the argument above obviously $(a_i){i \in \omega} \not \in \Sigma S$, and, with a little paperwork I can show that $(a_i){i \in \omega} \in \Sigma \Sigma S$. To be precise I can take $(a_i){i \in \omega}$ as the sum of the summable family $F := {f_t^{(1,j)}}{t \in \omega} \subseteq \Sigma S$, where: $$f_t^{(1,j)}(n)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $n \ne j$}\\1&\text{if $n = j$}\end{cases}$$ 1/2

$F$ is obviously summable and it's contained in $\Sigma S$ since every $f_t^{(1,j)} \in F$ is the sum of the summable family $F^{(t)} := {f_t^{(1,j,a)},f_t^{(1,j,b)}}\subseteq S$, where: $$f_t^{(1,j,a)}(n) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $n = 0$} \\
2 &\text{if $n = j$} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \qquad f_t^{(1,j,b)}(n) = \begin{cases} -1 &\text{if $n = 0$} \\  -1 &\text{if $n = j$} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ obviously $f_t^{(1,j,a)},f_t^{(1,j,b)} \in S$ and $F^{(t)}$ is summable. That's should be all for 2 and 3. Now I'll try to think carefully to 4. 2/2

(maybe there's some confusion with the indexing and $j$ is useless since I could've used just $t$, however the idea remains the same)

@IzaakvanDongen may I ask for more details about your hints for question 4? (If it's not a problem)

I've decided to write an answer to avoid too many comments, as the notation and
ideas for 4 are fairly involved.
I'll give some increasingly strong hints/tips/ideas in separate spoiler tags,
culminating in a full solution to 4. First I'll briefly summarise the ideas for
1-3 for completeness:

As you observed, the family $(\mathbf 1_{\{n\}} : n \in \Bbb N)$
of all indicator functions of singletons
is countable, and each subset is summable, so the indicator function of any
subset of $\Bbb N$ already belongs to $\Sigma C$, and there are
continuum-many of these. In fact, this family generates precisely
$\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$.
Let $I'$ be the set of $t$ such that $f_t \not\equiv 0$, and let
$X = \{(t, k) : f_t(k) \ne 0\}$. Then the first coordinate projection is a
surjection $X \to I'$. But also,
$|X| = \sum_{k \in \Bbb N} |\{t : f_t(k) \ne 0\}| \le \aleph_0$ by the
summability assumption,
so $I'$ is countable.
Since the zero component of each function in $S$ is nonzero, the only
summable families are the finite ones. Hence, $\Sigma S$ is the set of all
functions of finite support, and therefore $\Sigma \Sigma S$ is the set of
all functions, because for any $f$, we have
$f = \sum_{i \in \Bbb N} f(n) \cdot \mathbf 1_{\{n\}}$. In particular,
$\Sigma S \subsetneq \Sigma \Sigma S$.


Now for 4. Like I said, the strategy is to show that if
$(f_{a, b} : a, b \in \Bbb N)$ is a family of functions such that for each $a$,
the family $(f_{a, b} : b \in \Bbb N)$ is summable, and furthermore, the family
$(\sum_{b \in \Bbb N} f_{a, b} : a \in \Bbb N)$ is summable, then
there is some partition $\Bbb N^2 = X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \dotsb$ into finite sets
such that the family $(g_n = \sum_{(a, b) \in X_n} f_{a, b} : n \in \Bbb N)$
is summable (then since $S$ is closed under finite sums, $g_n \in S$ for each
$n$, and so the sum of the $g_n$ is in $\Sigma S$, which is what we want to
show). This is justified by part 2, and upon reading part 4, you can kind of
guess via "metagaming" that this is a good strategy - it's basically the only
natural/elementary thing you can do that gives you any leverage over the
problem. Now I will start going into more detail. What follows is basically a
guide to discovering my own solution - I don't know if there are other, nicer
solutions.

 First, remember that the partition $X_n$ is allowed to depend on the family
 $f_{a, b}$, and in fact it has to. Forget about the entirety of the domain for
 now - first try to show that there is always a partition such that the set
 $\{n \in \Bbb N : g_n(0) \ne 0\}$ is finite.


 Remember that this is equivalent to showing that the sequence
 $g_n(0)$ is eventually equal to $0$, and our hypothesis tells us that
 for each $a$, the sequence $f_{a, b}(0)$ is eventually zero as $b \to \infty$,
 and furthermore the sequence $\sum_{b \in \Bbb N} f_{a, b}(0)$ is eventually
 zero as $a \to \infty$ - so try thinking about this problem with your analysis
 hat on.


 If you're stuck, look at some examples. For example, can you think of such a
 partition for the family of functions defined by
 $f_{a, b}(0) = 1$ if $a = b$, $f_{a, b}(0) = -1$ if $b = a + 1$, and
 $f_{a, b}(k) = 0$ otherwise? Can you think of a family of functions for which
 your partition doesn't work, and then think of a partition that does work for
 that family? And so on...
 This problem should be visualisable, as we're only dealing with a
 two-dimensional grid of numbers here.


 A fairly large hint: look for a partition of the form
 $X_n = ([n + 1] \times [m_{n + 1}]) \setminus ([n] \times [m_n])$,
 where $m_n$ is a rapidly increasing sequence of naturals that you should
 construct. Here $[n]$ means $\{0, \dotsc, n\}$, so we're looking for a sequence
 of rectangles that are getting taller very quickly. Next, I will construct such
 an $m_n$.


 The key property that we want is that for each $n$, we have that
 $f_{a, b}(0)$ is $0$ for $a \le n + 1$ and $b > m_n$. It's clear that there is
 an increasing sequence $m_n$ with this property,
 because each $f_{a, b}(0)$ is eventually zero as $b \to \infty$. Next, I'll prove
 that $g_n(0)$ is then eventually zero.


 Indeed, choose an $N$ such that for $n > N$, we have
 $\sum_{b \in \Bbb N} f_{n, b}(0) = 0$. Then if $n > N$, we have $g_n(0) = 0$.
 This is because for each $a \le n$ and $b > m_n$, we have
 $f_{a, b}(0) = 0$, by construction of $m_n$. But also, we know that
 $\sum_{b \in \Bbb N} f_{n + 1, b}(0) = 0$
 and $f_{n + 1, b}(0) = 0$ for $b > m_{n + 1}$. Hence
 $\sum_{b \le m_{n + 1}} f_{n + 1, b}(0) = 0$. Therefore
 $g_n(0) = \sum_{b \le m_{n + 1}} f_{n + 1, b}(0) + \sum_{a \le n} \sum_{m_n < b \le m_{n + 1}} f_{a, b}(0) = 0$.
 
 So $g_n(0)$ is indeed eventually zero. Now you need to remember about the
 rest of the domain again, and try to modify this argument so that
 for each $k \in \Bbb N$, the sequence $g_n(k)$ is eventually zero. This is not
 too big of a step from here. I will finish the proof in the next section.


 The key point is that we've seen that we can find a sequence $m_n$ growing fast
 enough so that $g_n(0)$ will eventually be zero. In particular, observe that if
 $m_n'$ is any sequence such that eventually $m_n' \ge m_n$, then the
 corresponding functions $g_n'$ will have that $g_n'(0)$ is eventually zero.
 Similarly, we could find a sequence that grows fast enough to make $g_n(1)$
 eventually zero, and $g_n(2)$, and so on. To get our hands on a sequence that
 grows fast enough to make everything be eventually zero, we just need to
 diagonalise. Say that for each $k$, we have chosen a sequence $m_n^{(k)}$ that
 grows fast enough to make $g_n^{(k)}(k)$ eventually zero. Then we define our
 ultimate sequence to be $m_n = \max_{k \le n} m_n^{(k)}$. It follows that for
 each $k$, we eventually have $m_n \ge m_n^{(k)}$ as $n \to \infty$, so for each
 $k$, $g_n(k)$ is eventually zero. So $g_n$ is a summable family, and clearly
 $\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} g_n = \sum_{a \in \Bbb N} \sum_{b \in \Bbb N} f_{a, b}$.
 Hence, we are done.
 
 Of course, we could have skipped the whole detour via only thinking about
 $g_n(0)$ and instead just have defined $m_n$ directly. As always with these
 types of arguments, you have some freedom in where you ask for strict/non-strict
 inequality, or where you put the $+1$s.
 
 A small footnote is that strictly speaking, the assumption that all of the sums
 are infinite needs a bit of justification, since we might have been given some
 finite sums. This isn't really a problem though - if that's the case, then we
 can just pad everything out with zero functions, and then delete the zero
 functions again once we've constructed the $g_n$, also just deleting any $g_n$
 which is identically zero. This does not affect the sum or the summability of
 the $g_n$.


I don't have enough words to express the gratitude for your patience and helpfulness, thank you so much! :))

@lelouch_l8r4, you're welcome. It was a nice problem! Let me know if anything is unclear/confusing/wrong!
